# Elasticsearch cluster on Azure using ubuntu. The nodes don't see each other

Tags: ubuntu, azure, elasticsearch

I have been setting up a cluster of Elasticsearch in Azure, using Ubuntu VM, following the tutorial on the plugin page (elasticsearch-cloud-azure) on github. I've managed to configure everything and I have elasticsearch running, but I have 3 clusters of 1 Node instead of 1 Cluster of 3 nodes. I guess that the problem comes from:

`cloud:
    azure:
        keystore: /path/to/keystore
        password: your_password_for_keystore
        subscription_id: your_azure_subscription_id
        service_name: your_azure_cloud_service_name
discovery:
        type: azure`

I'm not sure of what "your_azure_cloud_service_name" should be. I have all my nodes inside a Virtual Network, so they can communicate each other. By default, on azure each time I create a VM, a new Cloud Service containing only that VM is created. Should that value be different for each of the nodes in my cluster?

I'm a bit lost on that one...

Answer (score 0):

When you created your virtual machines you had to provide a cloud service name, the first red box.

[image: create virtual machine dialogue]

the value in the first red box is the "your_azure_cloud_service_name". In order to use the elasticsearch-cloud-azure plug-in you will need to create all the Virtual Machines in the same cloud service.

Alternatively you can use the [zen discover](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html) that comes with elastic search, that however requires you to edit the elasticsearch.yml in a way that the host point to each other. Be aware that you can't use the multi cast option in Azure.